# Is there way to reconfigure LyX from terminal?

Tags: lyx, terminal-output, command-line

I can't find anything on the wiki.

I'm using a Mac OS X 10.11.6 if that helps.

https://wiki.lyx.org/Mac/Mac

## EDIT:

I was trying to find a shortcut for the tedious `Tools > Reconfigure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LyX actually calls a Python script that does the configure. So you can call it directly. If I wanted to configure the typical user directory, I would do the following:

1. Find my user directory by opening LyX and going to Help > About. For me, this is `~/.lyx`.
2. Find configure .py with `locate -i configure.py`. For me, this gives `/usr/share/lyx/configure.py`.
3. Then, just `cd` to your user directory and run `configure.py`.

Thus, I would do:

```
cd ~/.lyx && python /usr/share/lyx/configure.py
```

By the way, in the future it helps if you describe why you want to do something. I know that from your perspective, you probably think it's not relevant, but from the perspective of answering a question, it often helps. For example, I'm not sure if you want to configure the directory in the same user directory that is the default when you open LyX; or if you want to make a new user directory (e.g., have a different set of preferences from your main LyX).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! Sorry, I will know for next time to give more perspective. I did want to configure the directory in the same default user directory. For me, this default was `~/Applications/Lyx.app/Contents/Resources/configure.py`. I was just interested in a shortcut for `Tools > Reconfigure`.

Comment: @Jalep Thanks for the response! And no need to apologize--I just have learned some helpful tips when I ask questions myself and wanted to share :). Thanks for giving the location on macOS. That will be helpful to future users who come across this question. If anyone reads this and can share instructions for Windows, please do.